# How to set mod_wsgi for apache and django?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I know that there are already a lot of information on this topic, but they are quite clumsy, not so simple and expressive. 
Could anyone explain me how to use `django` and with `mod_wsgi` and `apache`?

Comment: -1. What's wrong with the actual documentation? What are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: @daniel - He/She is a new user. Its certainly not necesary to intimidate a new user by demoting their posts and scare them away for rest of their lives. A gentler reminder about providing more specific information would have been sufficient.

Comment: Although I am not a new user. I have been programming in python for 3 years. I still can not get that mod_wsgi working! fml

Comment: OOI did you get this running? I'm compiling a document that attempts to simplify Django deployment choices based on a user's needs, so I'd like to know how you got there in the end!

Answer (score 9):

mod_wsgi isn't particularly the best fit for running Python WSGI applications, or, if you'd rather, there are more pythonic ways you can run your Django instance.

First off, I'd reason that it takes a lot of effort to understand Apache's request processing model and to configure it correctly, especially with respect to mod_wsgi. If your not exactly set or locked into using Apache, I would recommend that you take a look at running [Spawning](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning) or [Green Unicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), behind a [nginx](http://nginx.net) proxy like @Neo suggested.

Spawning and gunicorn are both ridiculously fast, don't require that you compile Apache with a specific Python interpreter and provide support for progressively updating your code base on the fly, hooks for Django and other goodies out of the box. nginx, Spawning and gunicorn all have a simple processing model, are kept completely independent of each other, so you get a more transparent architecture that is easier to maintain and monitor.

Here's a great [guide](http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/spawning-django/) on setting up Spawning with Django by Eric Florenzano, and here's a [thorough presentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31915708/Gunicorn-Django-WSGI) on running Django with gunicorn by the project's author, Benoît Chesneau.

Whichever you choose, you'll be feeling right @home.

Comment: It isn't that difficult to configure mod_wsgi for a WSGI application. The problem is getting people to actually read the official documentation rather than relying on some arbitrary persons blog post about how they did it for their specific setup, one which may not be relevant to anyone else and may not even work for someone else. No matter, some people just don't have the mindset for understanding Apache and in that case alternatives may be more appropriate, especially so if you are some sort of Python purist who freaks over the idea of embedding Python in Apache.

Comment: BTW, Neo didn't suggest that they run Spawning or Green Unicorn behind a nginx proxy. They suggested running Apache/mod_wsgi behind the nginx proxy. For most people that isn't strictly necessary, but if trying to get the most out of Apache/mod_wsgi then using nginx in front as a proxy does bring various advantages which makes Apache/mod_wsgi perform better for real world traffic scenarios.

Comment: @Graham, yes I was solely referring to @Neo's suggestion about using nginx as a reverse proxy for serving static media, though I also see how that could have come out a bit wrong (and will qucikly jump to edit it). I'm here taking a healthy consideration, since the OP is obviously new to the game: Apache is a beast of it's own kind, add to that the unavoidable tantrum of configuring the `PYTHONPATH` for mod_wsgi with hardcoded configs or `site` and other trickeries... not to mention that aside from mod_wsgi Apache will serve no other purpose--by all means--go for Spawning or gunicorn!

Comment: @Graham, mod_wsgi is not that hard. But apache2 is! It keep showing me sth like "you have no permission to visit / "

Comment: @Peter. Watch the presentation at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations as it explains why you would get that.

Comment: Graham, as a developer who has been coding for around 30 years, I started with your official docs and found them incomprehensible. I don't blame people for looking in other places for a simpler howto.

Example:
'The Django framework provides the django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()... Using this function, a script file for a Django application which is compatible with mod_wsgi would be constructed as follows:'
What is that script meant to be called? Where do I put it? Is it the WSGI file? If so, why does it look so dissimilar to the version in the QuickConfigurationGuide? Etc etc.

Comment: [more...] you've obviously done a lot of work adding lots of exhaustive docs but it's tough getting a balance of just-in-case and just-in-time information. Latter needs it dumbed-down, and every bit of extra info adds to the noise. That's what the blogs are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

I recently setup my application on Django, and this guide was all that I needed. http://blog.stannard.net.au/2010/12/11/installing-django-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-10-04/

So basically, the process is

1. Setup another server to serve static files (Ex. Nginx) on Port 80.
2. Setup apache on some other port.
3. Run django application on apache using mod_wsgi
4. Reverseproxy all non-static/non-media files to apache+mod_wsgi/django

Let me know on which step you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it on my Mac, with Apache, Python and Django from Mac Ports. This is not necessarily the best approach but it works for me.

I have the following top-level directories:

- `lib`: python code, with settings.py in lib/settings.py
- `static`: stuff to be served by Apache, e.g. media and CSS
- `tools`: development tools, e.g. rollout scripts.

So here's the Apache config for an example site, then see Django WSGI script below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Stuff to served statically is in media directory
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/mysite/static

    ServerName mysite.local

    # Redirect to homepage action
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/$ /mysite/ [R,L]

    # Static dirs first
    Alias /static/ /Library/WebServer/mysite/static/

    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/mysite/static/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    

    # Now everything else goes to Django    
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite-django.local processes=1 threads=5 maximum-requests=0 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/Library/WebServer/mysite/lib python-eggs=/tmp
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite-django.local
    WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/mysite/lib/apache/django_wsgi.py

    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/mysite/lib/apache">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    

</VirtualHost>
```

The Django WGCI script is in lib/apache/django_wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: You can drop the 'processes=1' option to WSGIDaemonProcess as it defaults to a single process anyway. Using the 'processes' option results in a subtle difference with how wsgi.multiprocess flag is setup in WSGI environment which may come back and bite you if you ever want to use an in browser WSGI debugger.