# Deploying django websites in apache2 server

Tags: django, apache

I am looking for **step by step details of how to deploy django websites in apache2 server** with one example.
I am using ubuntu operating system

Please give some link or give the details.

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate, as well as a simple question which is easily answered by searching, it is also clearly a sysadmin question and therefore obviously belongs on Serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

There is a manual on Django [website](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/). There is also information about integration on ModWsgi [website](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango).

Comment: Obviously the choice it's up to the OP, though I'd go directly to Graham Dumpleton's ModWsgi documentation, it's fantastic and very enlighten. As a side note, also consider that Django manual stated to deploy Django using mod_python up until recently.

Comment: If you are going to use Apache/mod_wsgi, look first at 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide'. That is, try and get a simple WSGI hello world program working first. Seen so many cases where people just make it hard for themselves by trying to setup Django from the outset without first getting something simple working first so as to understand how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest to read official documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/), then try to see also [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/). And then if you face some problems, we SO is ready to help! :) Also I don't know if these [instructions](http://www.ventanazul.com/webzine/tutorials/django-deployment-guide-ubuntu) work (never tried, because it just first result showed by google), but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have searched Stack Overflow for questions similar to the one you have posted. Anyway, I'd like to point out here a significant post I have found.

[mod_wsgi in apache and django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978012/mod-wsgi-in-apache-and-django) (with a link for ubuntu too)

Hope this help.